# Automatic PR comment based on PR number

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I deploy PR-specific web applications and want to leave a link for testing purpose right in the stash PR page. The link is something like pr1234.application.com where 1234 is just a PR number. How can I do it? Can I avoid coding and use some existing extension?